# How to integrate QuickBlox in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, quickblox

I want to use QuickBlox for chat in react native. Can I use the javascript sdk provided by quickblox in react native ?

Answer (score 1):

Will this solution work? I got this from Quickblox official site.

https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/react-native-quick-start

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to use JavaScript library in React Native, that library should support React Native. 
As far as I know QuickBlox does not support it for now. So, probably you are going to face some issues if you try it.

However, there are some other providers who have added React Native support to JS SDK. 
For example, ConnectyCube.

Feel free to check also [React Native Chat samples](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples?id=chat-code-sample) and [documentation](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/react-native).